# How to use `fp_text_default ` function in flextable package

Tags: r-markdown, flextable, officer

I see there's a function in flextable package, namely `fp_text_default`. In help files to this function the only example you can find is

```
fp_text_default(bold = TRUE)
```

I was wondering if I can use this function to avoid setting `font.size=11` everytime I use custom formatting in my flextables, e.g.

```
flextable(df) %>%
  compose(value = as_paragraph(
    as_chunk("foo", props = fp_text(shading.color = "orange", font.size=11))
  )) %>%
  compose(value = as_paragraph(
    as_chunk("bar", props = fp_text(bold = TRUE, font.size=11))
  ))
```

The default font.size param in `fp_text` is 10 and I always have to set it to 11.

Can `fp_text_default` be used to set font.size to 11 permaently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set_flextable_defaults()` so that you don't have to call again and again `fontsize()` or some other functions (i.e. padding, color).

https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/set_flextable_defaults.html

`fp_text_default()` is a convenient function to overwrite only values that are specified, it keeps other formatting parameters as they are. So far more convenient than `fp_text()` that force you to specify all params...

Both can be used together...

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(flextable)
library(magrittr)
set_flextable_defaults(
  font.family = "Arial", font.size = 10,
  padding = 3, border.color = "gray"
)
```

```{r}
flextable(head(iris)) %>%
  append_chunks(
    i = 1, j = 1,
    as_chunk(" yo", props = fp_text_default(color = "red"))
  ) %>%
  autofit()


flextable(head(mtcars)) %>%
  append_chunks(
    i = 1, j = 1,
    as_chunk(" yo", props = fp_text_default(color = "red"))
  ) %>%
  autofit()

set_flextable_defaults(font.size = 12, padding = 5)
flextable(head(mtcars)) %>%
  append_chunks(
    i = 1, j = 1,
    as_chunk(" yo", props = fp_text_default(color = "red"))
  ) %>%
  autofit()

```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I noticed that even if you use `set_flextable_defaults` to set font size to 11 everytime you use `fp_text` the latter function sets font size back to 10 (which is default setting of `fp_text`). From now I'm switching to `fp_text_default` ;)

Comment: Yes, that is the motivation behind the fp_text_default